# Read time out when trying to list FTP server directory in Docker container on Linux

Tags: java, docker, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have service that polls FTP server with LIST command. I use local passive mode, use FTPSClient with following setting:

```
ftpClient.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
ftpClient.setDataTimeout(1800000); //30 minutes
ftpClient.setBufferSize(1281000000);
ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(120);
```

FTP server directory has around 700,000 files in it, so it takes time for server to respond. On my local machine by launching raw Java application it takes about 5 minutes to retrieve list of files, in Docker container on Windows it also works without problem in the same time, FileZilla - no problems, but longer. However, when I run the container on Linux machine (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS) it cannot retrieve the data despite the fact that it can connect to the server. After specified time in timeout setting I receive:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out    at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:?]  at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
> ~[?:?]    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
> ~[?:?]    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
> ~[?:?]    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
> ~[?:?]    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
> ~[?:?]    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
> ~[?:?]    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:185)
> ~[?:?]    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:326) ~[?:?]
> at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:392) ~[?:?]
> at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileEntryParserImpl.readNextEntry(FTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:53)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readStream(FTPListParseEngine.java:142)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readServerList(FTPListParseEngine.java:118)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3450)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3371)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3308)
> ~[app.jar:?]  at
> org.my.org.ftp.FtpOperator.listDirectory(FtpOperator.java:30)
> ~[app.jar:?]

I guess this is not problem with firewall, because I have similar service that polls external server and it works properly. Both services are using local passive mode of Apache FTP client library.

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ingest:
    image: pl/ingest
    ports:
      - "8038:8038"

    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./processedFiles:/processedFiles

networks:                                
  default:                               
    driver: bridge                       
    driver_opts:                         
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1500
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I could retrieve list by commandline FTP client(not FTPS). I run this application without Docker by running JAR file, which uses FTPS (actually gradle run command) and it also could listed directory. That all was on Linux machine.

Comment: Plain FTP work in Java, command-line FTPS client also works. Plain FTP does not work in Docker, either.

Comment: I mean that command-line FTP client works in the same environment where Docker's container not, both plain and FTPS. The Java JAR (gradle run) works in the same environment Docker's container not, both plain and FTPS. Neither plain FTP nor FTPS (in Java JAR) works in Docker's container .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing network mode from bridge to host in docker-compose made container able to list files by FTPS/FTP:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ingest:
    image: pl/ingest
    ports:
      - "8038:8038"
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/logs
      - ./processedFiles:/processedFiles
    network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem y reached to this [SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1623159/306866):

> ... active mode ftp is not suited for containerized ftp clients, due
> to the server actively trying to initiate a data connection to the ftp
> client, which is not possible for a container.

There are container workarounds but the programmatic way of solving this may be simpler: just change to passive mode after connecting.

```
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode()
```

And now it works for me.

Comment: I had local passive mode set on and still reached this problem on Docker container. This depends on FTP server. I had connected to FTP servers on local passive mode when I did not need to set network mode in container configuration. On this particular one I needed to.

Comment: Did you set the passive mode AFTER connecting?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, it worked for others FTP servers.